# Eclipse/CDT_C++ giving a "Semantic Error _"type XXX could not be resolved". The projects runs

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am completely new to programming and I am learning C++. I wrote a code to practice Functions with Return Values.  The code builds and runs, but there is an error message and I would like some help understanding it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void showMenu() {
    cout << " 1. Change personal information." << endl;
    cout << " 2. Search a Record." << endl;
    cout << " 3. Delete a Record." << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
}

int getInput() {
    cout << "Please select a menu item: " << flush;

    int menuNum;
    cin >> menuNum;

    return menuNum;
}

void processSelection (int options){
    int password = 12;
    int record = 4;
    int record2 = 5;

    switch (options) {
    case 1:
    ...
}

int main() {
    cout << "" << endl;

    showMenu();
    int menuSel = getInput(); 
    processSelection (selection);

    return 0;
}
```

I left out all the switch stuff because it takes up so much room. 
The error is in int main () at processSelection (selection);  It says "Type 'processSelection' could not be resolved."

Thank you

Comment: You probably wanted to pass `menuSel` instead of selection to `processSelection` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed undeclared identifier `selection` to `processSelection` function.
Just pass `menuSel` to `processSelection`, so your main should look like this:

```
int main() {
    cout << "" << endl;

    showMenu();
    int menuSel = getInput(); 
    processSelection(menuSel);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Elvis.  That did it.